# Evaluate the integral of a symmetric function excluding a interval of numbers

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I'm struggling with interpreting how to evaluate $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{[-M, M]\setminus(-\epsilon, \epsilon)} \frac{1}{x} \,dx$$ (The limit is taken from above).

I'm understanding that $[-M, M]\setminus(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ means the interval $[-M, M]$ without the interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.
At first I thought maybe we're evaluating the integral from $-M$ to $M$ but excluding the area that gets arbitrarly close to $0$, because there the integral would diverge to infinity. With my interpretation the value would simply be $0$ because of the symmetry of $\frac{1}{x}$ about the origin - and if we integrated from $-\epsilon$ to $-M$ and add the integral from $\epsilon$ to $M$ they would cancel each other out, avoiding the problems at the origin.

I would appreaciate a clarification as I'm not sure at all about my reasoning.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's right.  You can compute explicitly:
\begin{align*}
\int_{[-M, M]\setminus(-\epsilon, \epsilon)} \frac{1}{x} \,dx 
&= \int_{-M}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{x}\,dx + \int_{\epsilon}^M\frac{1}{x} \,dx \\
&= \left.\ln(-x)\right|_{-M}^{-\epsilon} + \left.\ln(x)\right|_{\epsilon}^M \\
&= \left(\ln \epsilon - \ln M\right) + \left(\ln M - \ln \epsilon\right) = 0
\end{align*}
So the limit of the above as $\epsilon\to 0$ is also $0$.